# Socket I - how does it connect back to the server automatically?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

As mentioned in this [tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for creating a chat application using Socket.IO :

> Notice that I’m not specifying any URL when I call io(), since it defaults to trying to connect to the host that serves the page.

I was wondering how did it do that? How can one through JavaScript on the client side retrieve the details of the server that served this very page? I tried searching through [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io), but wasn't able to find the `io()` function.

Can someone point that code that retrieves these meta-details or show a small snippet that does the same?

Comment: `I was wondering how did it do that?` - underpants gnomes - or `window.location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browser Javascript, the `window.location` object has these relevant properties:

```
window.location.host    - The hostname of the current webpage
window.location.port    - The port number of the current web page
```

Other properties are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

So, socket.io can use these two values to connect back to the host that the current web page came from.  You see some of this logic in the socket.io client side file here in [the source](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js#L1119).